# How to hold commit statment in oracle untill all scripts are executed

Tags: oracle, commit, rollback

I have 10 scripts, each script contains it's own commit statements. I'm executing all the scripts at the same time using my tool, which will ask for database connections and read our scripts and execute in our database.

I need to hold all commit statements in all scripts and if any statement fails in any script it should rollback all previous statements.

Answer (score 7):

Simply delete you commit statements.. AND

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;

{script 1}
{script 2}
{script 3}
{script 4}
.
.
.
{script 10}

COMMIT;
```

DDL will be committed implicitly on success. We do not issue commit for DDL. You should have a On failure script to have manual rollback.

For eg: you create two tables then have a rollback

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE; 
DROP TABLE1; 
DROP TABLE2;
```

Comment: All this should be in the same session

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay.
What about DDL commonds?? Is it handle??

Comment: DDL will be committed implicitly on success. We do not issue commit for DDL. You should have a On failure script to have manual rollback. For eg: you  create two tables then have a rollback `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE; DROP TABLE1; DROP TABLE2;`